# Inicializar un arreglo de matrices dentro de un objeto

Tags: c++

estoy tratando de hacer un tetris en c++, sin embargo a la hora de implementar los tetraminós no puedo. Estoy tratando de inicializar un arreglo de matrices dentro del constructor de un objeto, este es el código que me tira el siguiente error: "In constructor 'tetramino_O::tetramino_O()': error: assigning to an array from an initializer list"

```
typedef bool posicion[3][3];

class tetramino_O{
    int color;
    int pos;
    posicion posiciones[1];
        public:
            tetramino_O(){
                    posiciones = {
                    {
                     {0,0,0},
                     {1,1,0},
                     {1,1,0}
                    }
                };//posiciones
            }//constructor

};
```

Comment: Un tetramino "xxxx" no cabrá en una matriz de 3x3...

Comment: Ay sí, tienes razón, ¿en qué estaba pensando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay que destacar que lo que estas haciendo en el constructor no es una inicialización (ya que el array no está siendo declarado ahí, si no que ya está declarado anteriormente), sino una asignación al array. Los arrays estilo C no pueden ser asignados de la manera que tu intentas. Dicho esto, puedes inicializarlos directamente en la declaración, en vez del constructor, de esta manera el valor ya estará inicializado cuando ejecute el constructor:

```cpp
class tetramino_O {
    int color;
    int pos;

    posicion posiciones[1] = {
        {
            {0,0,0},
            {1,1,0},
            {1,1,0}
        }
    }; // posiciones

public:
    tetramino_O() {
        
    } //constructor
};
```

Una observación adicional: ¿Estas seguro que necesitas un *array* de 1 slot? No veo por qué querrias hacer eso, podrías trabajar directamente con una variable normal en vez de andar usando un slot que siempre va a ser 0 a lo largo del código:

```cpp
class tetramino_O {
    int color;
    int pos;

    posicion posiciones = 
    {
        {0,0,0},
        {1,1,0},
        {1,1,0}
    }; // posiciones

public:
    tetramino_O() {
        
    } //constructor
};
```

Comment: Gracias, sobre el tamaño del arreglo, es solo una prueba para los diferentes tetraminós que sí rotan y requieren más de un slot